# Determine all orthonormal vectors (x, y) that are orthogonal to the vector v (2, 8).

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, orthonormal

Given a vector $v = (2, 8)$, determine all vectors $w$ in form $(x , y)$ that are orthogonal to $v$. Vector $w$ must be orthonormal and therefore is a unit vector.

Knowing that the dot product of  $\langle u,w\rangle = 0$, I attempted to find a vector $w$ but my problem is how do I find all possible orthonormal vectors $w$ that are orthogonal? My initial instinct tells me it involves finding a basis but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hint: In the plane, a family of orthogonal vectors relative to one given vector is a one-parameter family.

Comment: $2x+8y=0\implies x=-4y$

Comment: are you asking for all vectors orthogonal to $v$, or only unit vectors, or both?

Comment: All vectors orthogonal to v with unit length so therefore unit vectors only.

Answer (score 1):

$(8,-2)$ and all its multiples are orthogonal to $(2,8)$.

Can you normalize $(8,-2)$; i.e., scale it so it's a unit vector (divide by the length)?

---

Another approach:  the orthogonality condition is $2x+8y=0;$ that means $x=-4y$.

The unit vector condition is $x^2+y^2=1$.

Can you solve $(-4y)^2+y^2=1$ for $y,$ and then solve for $x$ too?